# How to solve connection aborted error when uploading large file via python requests.post function?

Tags: python, python-requests, abort

I am trying to upload a compressed file using the python library `requests` via the following code

```py
files ={'compressed_file':open(compressed_file_path,'rb')}    
values={'Name_Column':column_name}
r = requests.post(url,  files=files, data=values)
```

When uploading a small file, the upload process runs smoothly however when uploading a file larger than 40 MB for instance, I encounter the following error:

> ```
> raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
> urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> ```

Is there something I should specify differently in the `requests.post` function? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Remote end closed connection" the server you are uploading to is severing the connection likely to prevent large uploads.

Comment: the server is basically an API based on python's FastAPI library. Do you think it has something to do with FastAPI library? thanks in advance